# Fixing java.util.NoSuchElementException for Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I resolve the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error?  I call the scanner object 3 times, and the program will accept input the first two times.  But on the third try, I immediately get the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error.  The name of the scanner object is `stdInput`.

I've tried creating a new scanner object just for the instance throwing this error, but I still get the same error, just from a different line in the code.

```
/**
 * reddit url:  https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/pjbj8/easy_challenge_2/
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class challenge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int choiceNum = 0;
        boolean continueRunningProgram = true;
        String repeatProgram = "";
        Scanner stdInput = new Scanner (System.in);

        do {

            System.out.println("Are you solving for force (1), mass (2), or acceleration (3)?");
            choiceNum = stdInput.nextInt();

            if(isValidChoiceNum(choiceNum) == false) {

                do {

                    System.out.println("The number " + choiceNum + " is an invalid choice.  Please choose again.");
                    choiceNum = stdInput.nextInt();

                } while(isValidChoiceNum(choiceNum) == false);

            }

            switch(choiceNum) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("The force is " + solvingForForce());
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("The mass is " + solvingForMass());
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("The acceleration is " + solvingForAcceleration());
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to solve another problem involving force, mass, and acceleration (Y/N)?");
            repeatProgram = stdInput.next();

            if(isValidChoiceChar(repeatProgram) == false) {

                do {

                    System.out.println("The letter " + repeatProgram + " is an invalid choice.  Please choose again.");
                    repeatProgram = stdInput.next();

                } while(isValidChoiceChar(repeatProgram) == false);

            }

            if(repeatProgram.compareTo("Y") == 0) {

                continueRunningProgram = true;

            } else {

                continueRunningProgram = false;

            }

        } while(continueRunningProgram == true);

        stdInput.close();

    } // end of main method

    public static boolean isValidChoiceNum(int c) {

        if(c < 1 || c > 3 ) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public static boolean isValidChoiceChar(String c) {

        if(c.compareTo("Y") == 0 || c.compareTo("N") == 0) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

    public static double solvingForForce() {

        Scanner stdInput2 = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a value for mass.");
        double m = stdInput2.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter a value for acceleration.");
        double a = stdInput2.nextDouble();

        stdInput2.close();

        return m * a;

    }

    public static double solvingForMass() {

        Scanner stdInput2 = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a value for force.");
        double f = stdInput2.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter a value for acceleration.");
        double a = stdInput2.nextDouble();

        stdInput2.close();

        return f / a;

    }

    public static double solvingForAcceleration() {

        Scanner stdInput2 = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a value for force.");
        double f = stdInput2.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter a value for mass.");
        double m = stdInput2.nextDouble();

        stdInput2.close();

        return f * m;

    }

} // end of class
```

Comment: Don't close a `Scanner` reading from `System.in`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the madness of closing a `Scanner` linked to `System.in`! It will close the underlying stream (`System.in`), causing any other attempt to read from that `Stream` to throw an exception.

Yes you will get a warning, but it is safe to ignore that warning, or you can add

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

To avoid it.

Remember, if you didn't open a resource, you shouldn't close it. Let the JVM close it when it terminates the program.

---

This also includes creating a `Scanner(System.in)` inside a try with resources block:

```
try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)){
   //Code... 
}
```

This will implicitly close the stream at the end of the block.

From the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

---

Also you have several `Scanner` objects reading from `System.in`, which is bad practice. I would pass them to your methods as a parameter:

```
public static double solvingForMass(Scanner in) {

    System.out.println("Please enter a value for force.");
    double f = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter a value for acceleration.");
    double a = in.nextDouble();

    return f / a;

}
```

---

Also just a note that if you are ever doing the structure of:

```
if(someBool)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

It can be simplified to just

```
return someBool
```

So your `isValidChoice()` method can be simplified to:

```
public static boolean isValidChoiceChar(String c) {
     return c.compareTo("Y") == 0 || c.compareTo("N") == 0;
}
```

Although note you can use the `equals()` and equalsIgnoreCase()`methods to compare`String`'s

Comment: Thank you so much @GBlodgett!!!  Not only did you resolve my issue, but you also gave me some other useful tips too.  Please feel free to provide any other suggestions you may have.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @NeoSoulPanther The only other suggesting I have is in your `if` statements, `if(validChoice(choice) == false)` can be rewritten to `if(!validChoice(choice))`

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks again for the suggestions!